# sending JSON as AJAX reponse. json_encode just not working?

Tags: php, ajax, json

Ive done some work before with encoding arrays into json objects and sending them, however this I just cannot get json-encode to work...

My script for sending out for the ajax response is as follows...

```
        function loadCalls(sid)
        {
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    innerText = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    aCall = document.createElement('div');
                    aCall.innerHTML = innerText;
                    document.getElementById("calls").appendChild(aCall);
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("POST","loadCalls.php",true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp.send("fname=<? echo $fname; ?>&lname=<? echo $lname; ?>&email=<? echo $email; ?>&sid=" + sid);
        }
```

And my php form code is as follows... What it simply does is build an array try to encode it to JSON, and then send it back to my loadCalls function above.

//Lets grab the uber long variable...

```
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$sid = $_POST['sid'];

//Array for all the tokens to go into...
$ourCalls = array();

//Our counter
$i = 0;

//Build the query
$querytokens = "SELECT * FROM lime_tokens_".$sid." WHERE firstname='".$fname."' AND lastname ='".$lname."'";

//execute query
$resulttokens = mysql_query($querytokens) or die ("Error in query: $querytokens. ".mysql_error());      

// see what rows were returned
while($rowtokens = mysql_fetch_row($resulttokens)) {
    $ourCalls[$i] = $rowtokens[5];
    $i++;
}

echo json_encode($ourCalls);

// free result set memory
mysql_free_result($resulttokens);

// close connection
mysql_close($connection);
```

If i just echo our the print_r $ourCalls, i get that text displayed, and my line of thought is that even if i left the code in part one the way i wanted, it would still show on my screen as the string. But i get nothing.

Please help :)

EDIT

The output of the print_r is :

```
Array ( [0] => b8r5x6w53d6cahw [1] => p5ugbeg68b4qixy ) 1
Array ( [0] => 4c85zznh955gjsc [1] => 2atggeb2hyg9mbj ) 1
Array ( [0] => z4kihguxfu2npx9 ) 1
```

What does the 1 at the end mean?

EDIT - dropped the echo, 1's are now gone.

Comment: What is the output of print_r($ourCalls)?  Have you checked your php error log?  Have you used something like Firebug or Chrome's console to check the precise response from the server?

Comment: print_r returns the php array and all its contents, perfectly, I can see this as the response in firebug also. However when I change to json_encode... i get nothing. no response at all.

Comment: Anything in the error log?  it would seem then that there's an issue with your array that's preventing it from being encoded as json.  Please can you post the *precise* output of `print_r($ourCalls)`?

Comment: Edited above response to include output

Comment: I've not idea where that `1` has come from; was there any other code that may have caused output alongside `print_r` (e.g., a typo)?  Why are there multiple arrays?  Did you call `print_r` on three different arrays?

Comment: Yes, this is data returned from an AJAX query. so the php script is run effecitvly 3 times in this senario. I need it to transfer json objects back to the script.

Comment: Okay.  Well the `1` must be getting sent in your code somewhere after the `print_r` call - could be anywhere, not necessarily immediately after it.  Regarding the `json_encode`, have you tried using [`json_last_error`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php)?

Comment: Yes tried, not getting any errors through :(

Comment: Hmm, how about trying: `$json = json_encode($ourCalls); var_dump($json);` to see precisely what is being returned?  I'm sorry I haven't the time at the moment to go into further discussion; I'll try to look back again later today!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using php 5.2+, as json_encode() does not exist in previous versions

Comment: Ah... I thought it was 5.1? would explain... I will go check/upgrade now!

Comment: It was that! I was running 5.1.6. Upgraded. Now fine! Thanks for your help and everyone envolved :)

Answer (score -2):

I cannot see your delimiters ?  , and ; and {} ?

Comment: I wanst aware I had to use delimiters in json_encode, or even with json.parse in javascript... Can you do me an example of what you mean please?

Comment: you select the fifth column relatively - but do not wrap it using delimiters - how come I get punished for this answer ?

Comment: Was not me that down voted you. However this is not the solution to the problem. Ive checked old code that works and when calling a variable theres no need to use delimiters. None that you specified anyway.

Comment: I think it should look like this: [item1, item2, item3] - ifg an array you should use [] and , to separate each value ?

Comment: JSON encode does all this for you. I think you are mis-understanding the point of the post... JSon encode is not working. Not the construct of the php array.

Comment: I have down-voted because this is not a very helpful answer - you are not specific enough about the solution; you should provide an example of a possible solution with an answer and a more detailed explanation.  Furthermore, from your comments above, this answer actually has nothing to do with the question at all.

Comment: I missed the json_ in the echo - sorry for that. But to get punished for that, does not inspire me nor motivate me. I still spend time doing this - not to brag not bother not to harraz, but to help ... I was looking for a way to delete my account. To loose points like that - hard earned - is not just ...

Comment: Mike, sorry my down-vote is not because your answer is wrong, but because it wasn't helpful.  You need to be more specific, like I said, give an explanation of what you think is wrong that references precisely where in the OP's code the error can be found, then give some proper example code that can be used instead.  I think it's great that you're here to help, that's what we're all trying to do, and I'm trying to help *you* to improve the quality of your answers.  If you work on that, then I'm sure you'll get many up-votes in the future!